# matching properties of serde

Tags: amazon-athena, presto, trino

It seems that I am able to create tables with invalid properties.
For e.g. "some_junk" is not valid property of csv serialization. The statement should fail.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test2 (
f1 string,
s2 string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("some_junk" = ",", "escapeChar" = "\\") 
LOCATION 's3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/dataset/test1/'
```

I was expecting an error because of "**some_junk**". But the statement was executed successfully.

Comment: this is a limitation that lies with OpenCSVSerde and most of the times DDL will run fine although you give incorrect schema/properties that are different from actual data. It fails when you try querying table that you created.

Comment: This is happening with any serde and not just OpenCSV

Comment: How difficult is it to check the validity of property for a given serde?

Comment: Athena does mostly schema on read which indicates the reason for the behaviour that you are seeing

Comment: It checks the general syntax. Right? then why can't it check if property match with the given serde?

Comment: this should be a more of a serde issue and you can file an issue here https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde

Comment: Done! https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde/issues/48